# How to make a window position to bottom on submit event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom-events

I got a page with few drop down fields and when I submit the page it returns with a data from mysql just below the fields. I want to make this page positioned to bottom when the user clicks the submit button. Currently I tried the below script:

```
function md()
{
//window.location.hash="code";
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

This works in Mozilla, but not in IE. Is there any other alternative for the above code? My submit button has an onclick event which calls two javascript functions:

```
onClick='selectAllOptions("countryRF");md();return false;'
```

So in IE while I click its coming to bottom but when data appear its back to top again?
Please help me!

Comment: Do not have onclick of submit instead have onsubmit of the form tag or make the submit button a type=button

Comment: its a php page if change submit to button post data not working.

Comment: Ahem.. You return false anyway so the submit is cancelled!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="selectAllOptions('countryRF');setTimeout(md, 1000);return false;">
```

It is better to use `onsubmit` for the `form` rather than to use `onclick` for the button, as people using a keyboard, screenreader, braille terminal etc. won't be able to trigger a `click` event.

The code I have added is `setTimeout(md, 1000);`, it fires the function `md` after 1 second, because the page will probably not take less that a second to update.

**EDIT:**

That probably won't work.

Try adding `name="form"` to your form, and using this in the `head` section of your page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form'])) {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    };
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this works fine.. but my page is inside drupal 6. so when I clcik submit from firefox nothing is happening ? but it work charm in IE !.. how can I make it work in all browsers ? @Shaquin Trifonoff

Comment: @Gopipuli - Are you actually submitting the form? You have `return false;`. IE understands `return false;` and Firefox/all browsers other than IE understand `event.preventDefault();`. So you could try `onsubmit="event.preventDefault();selectAllOptions('countryRF');setTimeout(md, 1000);return false;"`, but I still don't know *exactly* what you want and what the problem is.

Comment: code in header not working but the first one as I said works in IE -:(

Comment: @Gopipuli - What do you see in the `<head>` when you click View Page source or View Source?

Comment: okey this is what I am trying to do.. i got a submit button on page (drupal 6) while clicked return a data table which will make the page scroll. So I just want to postion my page to bottom so that users can have a proper view of data table. Your code on for onsubmit work in IE but not in FF. Also tried the php code in header but its not working ? thank you for responses!

Comment: @Gopipuli - Is the data returned like a standard form, or are you using AJAX?

Comment: data returned like normal form used php, but after that I use ajax for sorting it

Comment: @Gopipuli - Can you provide a link to your page?

Comment: thank you.. the php code works ! I had a section where I check whether the form post data empty or not.. I placed your code there and it works fine ! -:)) thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This jquery function will scroll to you to the bottom of the page, if that's what you want to do:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

so you could throw that into the function: `function md() { [the code above] }`

be sure to load jquery though, place this in your `<head>` of the page:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: nopes, this works when I click the submit button, but when the data is loaded the page is going back ? @iight